# Wampserver data restoration

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I reinstalled my wampserver 3.1.0, but i forgot to export my database.
I've read through different options of restoring my old datas using the old data found in C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.19\data.

I reinstalled the same verion of wampserver and replaced the data file with the old datas.

After restarting wampserver, it refuse to turn green, but if I remove the old ibdata1 and replace it with the new ibdata1 from the new installation.

Wampserver then turns green. Please anyone with a solution to this.

Thanks

Comment: What errors are there in the mysql error log

Answer (score 0):

If the data is in the correct folder, it will be visible in MySQL, or you will get errors when the server starts. Check /var/log/messages and your MySQL error log (as defined in your config).

If you don't get any errors and can't see the data, if that does not help please check out this thread: 
https://superuser.com/questions/1328965/how-to-restore-mysql-database-using-files-on-data-folder